# Server side message data security

Tags: javascript, security, node.js

What is the best way to sanitize message content on the server side which is received from client as one of the query string parameters? This message is also meant to be resend to other connected clients so it have be secure in terms of code execution or injection (JavaScript or HTML) on server or client side.

Comment: What is your server-side technology? Javascript is purely client-side so the server-side sanitization is done in whatever programming language you are using at the server end. Example server-side languages would be PHP, Java etc

Comment: He's using node.js. http://nodejs.org/  Unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge to answer his question with that server-side technology.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent by sanitizing the data? SQL injection? XSS?

Comment: This totally depends on what exactly is going to be done with the data, through what protocols it is going to be re-sent etc. There is no general answer for this.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Prevent XSS and server side code execution (don't know if it's possible in this case because node.js is JS code and you can send malicious JS code as a query string parameter to be executed on the server side).

Comment: @Pekka: HTTP since it's a long polling server, communication transport is based on JSONP. Received request query string is parsed into JSON object which should contain "content" field with message data. Now message sanitation should take place and then it's resent to other clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To protect node.js against XSS I borrowed this from snippet [jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/lib/jade.js#L118):

```
/**
 * Escape the given string of `html`.
 *
 * @param {String} html
 * @return {String}
 * @api private
 */

function sanitize(html){
    return String(html)
        .replace(/&(?!\w+;)/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

**P.S:** You should always do proper server-side filtering

Answer (score 2):

You could use [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator), it looks like a more comprehensive solution to the aboce snippet.